# Roles and policies in Postgresql 9.5 row-level security

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, role, row-level-security, authorization

Following the the info in posts like [these](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/choice-of-authentication-approach-for-financial-app-on-postgresql) i would like to use the role system and policies, i.e. each user in my system would have a db role.
I want to model the following properties but i can't come up with a role hierarchy.

Consider the following tables:

`companies(id, name)
users(id, name)
projects(id, name, company_id)
users_companies(user_id, company_id, type)
users_projects(user_id, project_id)`

each user can have a different type within a company (admin/employee/customer) and depending on that the policy should change.
So when a user is authenticated, we know his user_id and company_id
Those can be provided id needed in policies with things like

`set local user_vars.user_id = 10
set local user_vars.company_id = 20`

What would be the roles and policies needed in order to get this

- you can see only your company row in the companies table
- admins can see all the projects for their company
- employees can see only the projects they are assigned to
- no one can see/alter entries in users_companies (that is done somehow on signup and with triggers)
- admins can see the users_projects entries but only related to the users and project in their company
- employees can see users_projects entries only for projects that they are assigned to
- admins can see all the users in their company
- employees can see the  users in their company that participate in the same projects as they do

I am looking for a base case that i can build on. My main problem is the fact that a user can have different roles/types depending on the current company

Comment: I think the problem is simplified a bit if i think that each user could have separate db roles depending in which company he wants to authenticat, so for for user joe there could be 2 roles joe_company_1 and joe_company_2 and you could do grant admin to joe_company_1 and grant employee to john_company_2

Comment: Relying on session variables (`user_vars.company_id`) seems like a security bug. Anyone who can connect to the database could use `SET` to evade RSPs.